# How to set background of stackpanel when it is pressed in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, styles, expression-blend, pressed, visualstates

How to set a background color of stackpanel(grid or border) using visualstate when it is pressed in Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 0):

By tags I can see you're familiar with VisualStates. StackPanel doesn't have VisualStates. You want it to behave like a button - so set your StackPanel as the content of the Button and manage VisualStates of the Button.